# char data type in C

Tags: c

In a C book says that char data type can memorise numbers and ascii characters. How the computer knows if I refer to a character or to a number? For example, if I want to print on screen the value of a char variable, how computer knows if I refer to the ascii character for that number or I refer to that number?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler doesn't necessarily handle this automatically. In C, this is handled in console output via **format specifiers.**

```
printf("This is a char:%c\n", 'c');
printf("This is an int:%d\n", 3);
```

If you provide the wrong data type as the argument corresponding to the format specifier in your format string, you will get compiler warnings:

```
printf("This is a char:%c\n", 1); // WARNING: Implicit conversion from (int) to (char) (due to implicit down-cast)
```

You may not get such a compiler warning depending on the verbosity level if you provide an argument that is smaller than what was expected, ie:

```
printf("This is an int:%d\n", 'b'); // Implicit up-cast
```

So, in short, the format specifier lets the compiler know how to represent the data when it comes to printing it to the console, and will also do type-checking between the format specifiers and the corresponding arguments if there is a mismatch.

Finally, if your compiler is C99 compliant, printf will convert an integer to its character-literal equivalent if you have a type-mismatch:

```
printf("This is a char:%c\n", 99); // Prints the 'c' character literal
```

You can find the character/number mappings here:

http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: You could point out how printing 'c' with %d will print 99 as that is the ascii value of 'c'.

Answer (score 2):

**According** to "[The C Programming Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language)", 2nd Edition,
*Section A4.2* "Meaning of Identifiers" : "Basic Types", Page 195

> Objects declared as characters (`char`) are large enough to store any member of the execution character set. If a genuine character from that set is stored in a `char` object, its value is equivalent to the integer code for the character, and is non-negative.

and therefore, the following works (if the [character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aCharacter_sets) is [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), i.e. The following example is for [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII))

```
int n = 65; //is equal to 'A' in ASCII
char c = 'A'; //is equal to 65 in ASCII
printf("%c %d", n, c); //should print "A 65" despite the "wrong" order
```

**According** to Page 244, "Standard Library", "Formatted Output", "`printf` functions"
For the '%c' format specifier, printf does the following: convert `int` to `unsigned char`

> `int`; single character, after conversion to `unsigned char`.

Comment: do you feel the code sample is a comprehensive answer for the OP? Could you add value here?

Comment: @DaveA sorry, i was on my phone, Updated.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

you give format to `printf()`

if you use:

```
char c = 'c';
printf("%c \n", c); //result is the character 'c'.
printf("%d \n", c); //result is 99, the ASCII value of character 'c'.
```

but note never to use format %d for char in scanf, this may destroy your stack.

```
scanf("%d \n", &c); //NEVER do this.
```

Comment: thanks! I understood. :) But in C++, how the computers knows if char is number or a character at printing?

Comment: in c++ just cast to int. `cout<<c;` will print the character, `cout<<(int)c;` will print the ASCII value.